# Specify visual studio 2012 version in python pip command

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6 on a windows 7 system. It has visual studio 2012 installed and also visual studio 2014 's version installed. The visual studio 2014 is not complete. However, python is referring to visual studio 2014 and on running

```
pip install airflow
```

it uses visual studio 2014 and gives following  error

```
    c:\users\mag\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such
ory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

How can I specify python to instead use visual studio 2012 as that is a complete installation and has io.h as well ?